# How to create a list of objects which are one-way associated with objects of another model in SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have models **Playlist.js** and **User.js**. I want to have a list of users in Playlist who can answer for the comments on them. I do not want the attribute to appear in User. (i.e. one-way-association)

Playlist.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: 
        },        
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 128,
            required: true
        },
        // many to many relationship with role
        roles_with_access: {
            collection: 'role',
            via: 'playlist',
            through: 'rolehasplaylist'
        },

        // THIS ATTRIBUTE ASSOCIATE WITH ONE USER
        // BUT INSTEAD OF THAT I WANT A LIST OF USERS
        users_who_can_answer_comments: {
            model: 'user'
        }
    }
};
```

User.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 128,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: 'email',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        adminRole: {
            model: 'role'
        }
    }
};
```

Sails documentation have mentioned one-way association only for one-to-one mapping - http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-way-association
**I want to find a way to have a list of users with associations to users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change model to collection:

```
users_who_can_answer_comments: {
    collection: 'user'
}
```

Comment: So is it just like a one-to-many, without mentioning the playlist from the user side?

Comment: Yes, exactly ;)

Comment: can I use the `via` and `through` properties and create the association model too. Otherwise it creates a table with a very long name ('playlist_users_who_can_answer_comments__user_users_who_can_answer_comments_user') and gives an error. `error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: ER_TOO_LONG_IDENT: Identifier name 'playlist_users_who_can_answer_comments__user_users_who_can_answer_comments_user' is too long`